python object cleanup order - can I use object reference to force GC to collect another object first?
I have 2 objects a, b (instances of A,B respectively) that are created inside my app:
class A:
    def __del__(self):
        print("A.__del__")


class B:
    def __del__(self):
        print("B.__del__")

a = A()
b = B()

this would print out (on my machine :) ):
A.__del__
B.__del__

which means, that in this case, the garbage collection order is the creation order.
What I need, is to force the garbage collection order, so that a would be destroyed after b. I tried keeping a inside b:
b._guard = a

but that didn't help, and a was destroyed first (at least the __del__ functions were called in the same order).
My real world case is using pybind11, where a grandparent creates a parent which then creates a child, and that child must be destroyed before the grandparent. Keeping self of the grandparent inside the child seems to work, but in this simple case I'm asking it clearly doesn't so I don't think that is a robust solution.
It seems that py::keep_alive might have helped me if my case was parnent and child, but since there is no connection between the grandparent and the child, I think its irrelevant.
Is there a pure pythonic way (or a neat pybind11 way) to force the grandparent to be kept alive until the cleanup of the child?

Python's main GC mechanism is reference counting, so keeping a reference in the child should work. It only resorts to global garbage collection when there are circular references. In that case I don't think you have control over the collection order.

@Barmar thanks for answering. I don't understand then how come my example didn't work (and my real piece of code did seem to work...)

Good question. This only happens when you exit python? Since everything becomes garbage then, it might not bother following references.

The intended meaning of "destroyed" is unclear, although that's not your fault ;-) This is subtle stuff.
To me, "destroyed" means Python releases the underlying memory, so that any future reference to it may lead to a segfault. But that's emphatically not what calling __del__() means. __del__ is just another Python-level function, with the twist that the implementation will (probably) call x.__del__() if it's considering releasing x's memory.
Whether it does go on to release the memory depends on what __del__() does. The classic example:
   some_global_list = []

   def __del__(self):
       some_global_list.append(self)

In that case, self's memory is not released. self "resurrected" itself by appending itself to a global list (or in any other way made self reachable "from outside" again).
Python intends never to release memory so long as there's any conceivable way to reach the object's memory again. In particular, in the case of cyclic gc, all "destructors" are called before any memory in the cycles' objects gets released. So you may, e.g., see a million lines of "__del__ was called" output before any memory is released. And, indeed, if any of __del__() methods resurrected the cycle(s), it's possible that no memory will be released.
So I think you need to take pains to specify more precisely exactly what it is you're trying to prevent. In general, no, there is no way to force the order in which memory is released. There is no defined "garbage collection order". In simple cases "creation time order" may appear to be the case, just because of the order objects happen to be added to the internal doubly-linked list of gc'able objects. As time goes on, that list gets partitioned and reordered in various ways, as a side effect of running cyclic gc and as surviving objects are moved to older "generations".
But none of that "should" matter to the semantics of sane code.
